# Scroll text on hover for each list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have found a fiddle that shows how to scroll a text on hover. Here only first div element is scrolling on hover. but i want scroll text for each list `li` element on hover like in fiddle (i want change div to li  ). please check.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q885t7u0/)

On hover other `li` the scrolling text should stop to pre state.

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q885t7u0/2/)

Because you are usind same id's `<div id="container">`for all div which is not proper.
Use class`<div class="container">`for all div